# codeigniter routes config for backend and frontend

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to have this site structure>

```
site>application>controllers
  >backend
    Admin.php
  >frontend
    Main.php
```

So when I enter to my site it should be>

- when accessing to website> http://example.com
- when accessing to admin website> http://example.com/admin

So far I could not make it. I could only make work the frontend main page with this structure>

```
site>application>controllers
  >backend
  >frontend
  Main.php (outside frontend folder)
```

and in routes.php:

```
  $route['default_controller'] = 'main/index';
```

how can I configure codeigniter so I can have what I need?

Comment: you have to include the folder where your main.php is.. for example: `$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/main/index';`.. just try this..

Comment: @d_unknown sorry this is not working

Comment: I tried that structure on my project and it worked so far..

Comment: @d_unknown how do you handle the index.php?

Comment: Since it is outside the application folder and is already included by default, I do not include it anymore.. do you have index function inside your main.php?

Comment: @d_unknown I have one already, recently realized that I needed that. So know even though I have it, it can-t seem to work with the given path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$config['admin'] = 'backend/Admin'; #http://example.com/admin
$route['some_name'] = 'frontend/some_name'; #http://example.com/some_name
$route['default_controller'] = 'main'; #http://example.com/
```

In `'default_controller'` you no need to define `index` it will call automatically.

Comment: I just want to know I have to add this code in route.php file, right? also I have add $config['admin'] = 'backend/Admin';  in route.php?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config['backend/Admin'] = 'admin';               // http://example.com/admin
$config['default_controller'] = 'frontend/Main';  //http://example.com/
```

Comment: Did you implement `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Yes I do implement it... and sorry but this is not working for me either

Comment: Where should I add this code? Please share the file name

Comment: @user9437856 , file name: routes.php

Comment: Are you sure routes.php will accept the $config? because I tried but it's not working. Give me an error object not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In router.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/main/index';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "backend/$1";
```

Comment: I need to know after adding $route['admin/(:any)'] = "backend/$1"; which controller it will call? because I have more then 4 controller name